# Deploy Service Fabric service with different names using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric application with one service (MyService). 
Right now I'm building the app with a build pipeline and then deploying the artifact using a release pipeline to a cluster hosted on Azure.

What I want is to create multiple instances of the service on the same cluster with different names (like DEV_MyService, QA_MyService). The ideal option will be to use one artifact and multiple stages in the release pipeline.

Is there a way to achieve that with Azure DevOps and the release pipeline?

I was trying to parameterize the service name but it seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways:

1. Create a new [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-sfctl-service#sfctl-service-create) inside an existing application:

```
sfctl application create --app-name fabric:/TestApp --app-type TestAppType --app-version 1.0
sfctl service create --app-id TestApp --name fabric:/TestApp/TestSvc1 --service-type TestServiceType --stateless --instance-count 1 --singleton-scheme
sfctl service create --app-id TestApp --name fabric:/TestApp/TestSvc2 --service-type TestServiceType --stateless --instance-count 1 --singleton-scheme
```

2. Create a service in multiple applications (of one application type):

```
sfctl application create --app-name fabric:/TestApp1 --app-type TestAppType --app-version 1.0
sfctl application create --app-name fabric:/TestApp2 --app-type TestAppType --app-version 1.0
sfctl service create --app-id TestApp1 --name fabric:/TestApp/TestSvc --service-type TestServiceType --stateless --instance-count 1 --singleton-scheme
sfctl service create --app-id TestApp2 --name fabric:/TestApp/TestSvc --service-type TestServiceType --stateless --instance-count 1 --singleton-scheme
```

If you want to make this parameterizable, you can use a [task that replaces placeholders](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) inside files.

The script file (for example #1) would look like this:

```
sfctl application create --app-name fabric:/__appName__ --app-type TestAppType --app-version 1.0
sfctl service create --app-id __appName__ --name fabric:/__appName__/__serviceName__ --service-type TestServiceType --stateless --instance-count 1 --singleton-scheme
```

And you would need to specify two Azure DevOps pipeline variables:

1. appName
2. serviceName

define a different value for every stage.